# parsing tchars using _tcstok_s in winapi

Tags: winapi, parsing, token, delimiter, tchar

With the following code I get an error "Unhandled exception at 0x59be5d2e (msvcr100d.dll) in simpleWindow.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00e750f8."

```
TCHAR *string1 = _T("last.first");
TCHAR *delim = _T(".");
TCHAR *context;
TCHAR *name = _tcstok_s(string1, delim, &context);
```

This is just an example I'm using, ultimately I am trying to pull in a string from another class, but I wanted to get the parsing working first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:-

```
TCHAR string1[] = _T("last.first");
```